# jquery runs only with log()

Tags: jquery, logging

Hi I have a small jquery script which takes data from a button, use this as an id for a container and toggle the class of the container.
The script works fine but only if I have "log(audioId);" enabled. If I delete this part the script is not working. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
jQuery (document).ready(function($){
        var playing = false;
        var btns = $('[data-music]');
        $(btns).each(function() {
        $('[data-music]').on('click', function(e) {
        var FFplayer = $(this).data('music');
        $("#" + FFplayer).toggleClass("audio-hidden audio-shown");
            var audioId = $("#" + FFplayer).find('audio').attr('id');
            if (playing == false) {
                $("#" + audioId)[0].play();
                playing = true;
            } else {
                $("#" + audioId)[0].pause();
                playing = false;
                }

            log(audioId);                       
    });
});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to do both selecting all `[data-music]` items into `btns` and loop through them all? I think this would give you the same behavior without doing the `$(btns).each` ? inside the inner function `this` should refer to each `[data-music]` element.

```
jQuery (document).ready(function($){
    var playing = false;
    $('[data-music]').on('click', function(e) {
            var FFplayer = $(this).data('music');
            $("#" + FFplayer).toggleClass("audio-hidden audio-shown");
            var audioId = $("#" + FFplayer).find('audio').attr('id');
            if (playing == false) {
                $("#" + audioId)[0].play();
                playing = true;
            } else {
                $("#" + audioId)[0].pause();
                playing = false;
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks. Just beginning with jquery. This helps. :-)